# ! Missing \endcsname inserted . Problem with \def

Tags: pdftex, definition

I am trying to compile and OLD LaTex file from my PhD thesis, using PDFLatex. However, now it does not compile anymore. It keep me giving this error. Below I give a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{isolatin1,epsfig,makeidx,prbbib1,color,latexsym}
%\usepackage[pdftex, pdftitle={Article}, pdfauthor={Author}]{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF
\usepackage[pdftex, pdftitle={Article}, pdfauthor={Author}] % For hyperlinks in the PDF
%\usepackage{underscore}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\skip1{\vskip \baselineskip}
\def\skip2{\vskip 2\baselineskip}
\def\chaptername{Cap\'{\i}tulo}
\def\refname{{\bf Bibliografia}}
\def\bibname{Bibliografia}
\def\appendixname{Ap\^endice}
\def\ao{\~ao }
\def\cc{\c{c}}
\def\cao{\c{c}\~ao }
\def\beq{\begin{eqnarray}}
\def\endeq{\end{eqnarray}}
\def\vetor{\stackrel{\rightarrow}}
\def\tensor{\stackrel{\leftrightarrow}}
\def\adaga{a^{\dagger}}
\def\figurename{Figura}
\def\contentsname{Sum\'{a}rio}
\def\indexname{\'{I}ndice Alfab\'{e}tico}
\makeindex
%\pdfcompresslevel=9
%\pdfoutput=1
\begin{document}
\hyphenation{res-fria-da e-ner-gia exis-t ge-ne-ra-li-za
des-co-ber-ta cor-res-pon-den-te re-su-mi-da-men-te
con-si-de-ra-vel-men-te se-me-lhan-tes par-ti-cu-lar li-miar
de-sem-pe-nham pa-ra-le-lis-mo di-fluo-re-tos es-pa-lha-men-to
re-ve-lou co-nhe-ci-do me-dia-do re-la-ti-va-men-te mo-di-fi-ca
e-xa-mi-nar tem-pe-ra-tu-ra a-vel subs-tra-to e-xi-be va-lo-res
e-xis-te e-xis-tem con-si-de-ra-das di-fe-ren-tes ca-mi-nho
cor-res-pon-den-te des-cre-ven-do li-ne-a-res cons-ti-tu-ti-va
des-cre-ve-re-mos cor-res-pon-den-tes o-pe-ra-do-res le-ve-men-te
par-ti-lha-mos a-gra-de-ci-men-tos cons-tan-te me-ta-mag-ne-ti-cos
mag-ne-tos-ta-tic des-pre-za-mos e-xem-plo lo-ca-li-za-dos
an-ti-pa-ra-le-las con-si-de-rar} \pagenumbering{roman}
%\typeout{Agradecimentos}
%\include{ack}
%\typeout{Resumo}
%\include{res}
\typeout{Abstract}
%\include{abs}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\include{cap1}
%\include{cap2}
%\include{cap3}
%\include{cap4}
%\include{cap5}
%\include{apenda}
%\bibliographystyle{Prsty1}
%\bibliography{bib}
%\printindex
\end{document}
```

and it gives the log file:

```
Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "main.tex"
Startup Folder: F:\SkyDrive\FISICA\a.__MY_THESIS\PhD\NEWVERSION

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-05>
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo)) (./isolatin1.sty
ISO-latin-1 input coding, version 0.9 of 1-Jun-1992.)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/epsfig.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/makeidx.sty) (./prbbib1.sty
Filename: prbbib1 .sty, v3.1 <7/1/1996>
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.7 \def\skip
             1{\vskip \baselineskip}
? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on main.log.
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `\usepackage[pdftex, pdftitle={Article}, pdfauthor={Author}]` is missing `{hyperref}`.

Comment: `\def\skip1{\vskip \baselineskip}\def\skip2{\vskip 2\baselineskip}` could never have worked, the second definition over-writes the first, so the first does nothing and the second one breaks the tex `\skip` primitive. (That isn't the cause of the error shown but ...)

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer, this solved my problem!!

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle!